# Cannot create a new post from django admin panel, but from python shell it's created

Tags: python, mysql, django

From the python shell I can add a new post to my database but from the Django admin panel it's showing a type error. I am using Django with MySQL.
with SQLite3 It's working fine but what is the problem with MySQL?

Here is the error with complete trackback:

```
TypeError at /admin/blog/post/1/change/
not all arguments converted during string formatting
Request Method: POST
Request URL:    http://127.0.0.1:8000/admin/blog/post/1/change/
Django Version: 2.1.1
Exception Type: TypeError
Exception Value:    
not all arguments converted during string formatting
Exception Location: F:\myproject\venv\lib\site- 
packages\django\db\models\lookups.py in process_lhs, line 157
Python Executable:  F:\myproject\venv\Scripts\python.exe
Python Version: 3.6.4
Python Path: ['F:\\myproject',  
             'F:\\myproject\\venv\\Scripts\\python36.zip',
        'C:\\Users\\Anuj\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python36\\DLLs',
        'C:\\Users\\Anuj\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python36\\lib',
        'C:\\Users\\Anuj\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python36',
        'F:\\myproject\\venv',
        'F:\\myproject\\venv\\lib\\site-packages',
        'F:\\myproject\\venv\\lib\\site-packages\\setuptools-39.1.0- 
         py3.6.egg',
        'F:\\myproject\\venv\\lib\\site-packages\\pip-10.0.1-py3.6.egg']
         Server time:   Fri, 7 Sep 2018 18:28:47 +0000
```

Here is the complete traceback of my error [complete traceback](http://dpaste.com/1E9NN51)

[Django admin panel](https://i.stack.imgur.com/791zb.png)

Comment: Can you please share the complete traceback.

Comment: complete trackback added @ArpitSvt

Comment: `not all arguments converted during string formatting` , you're probably doing a string formatting to create a insert statement or something, and it's throwing the error. Please show your query

Comment: i am just inserting data from Django admin panel@user2906838